# UIImageView call method CGRect. How can I do this?

Tags: xcode, uiimage, rect

I have a UIImageView, I added init..

```
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0 ,-20, 780, 50);
        imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        [self addSubview:imageView];
```

and

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
    if (self.itemCount == 0) return;

    int drawedUpToXPosition = 0;

    ...............
}
```

How can I call `(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method at `UIImageView object (imageView)`. I want to Rect inside in `imageView`. Please help.

---

I have a DrawRect method and i will drawing at image. And I used

```
- (void) onTimer:(NSTimer *) theTimer
{
    if (!self.timerIsRunning)
        [theTimer invalidate];

    for (int i = 0; i < self.itemCount; i++)
    {
        TickerItem *ticker = [itemList objectAtIndex:i];
        if (ticker.isVisible)
            ticker.currentX -= 1;
    }


}
```

function.  How can I call DrawRect method?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You don't call `drawRect` directly. You tell your view it needs to draw itself by sending it the `setNeedsDisplay` message:

```
[myView setNeedsDisplay];
```

I think that is what you are asking, your question is not very clear.